# which process has start my db?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have to restart a database, but it seems, it has not been start by the good process:

```
ps -ef | grep smon | grep mydb
oracle 54621  1 0 2021 ?    00:10:55 ora_smon_mydb

. oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [oracle] ? mydb
The Oracle base has been set to /product/oracle/1120



sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL*Plus realease 11.2.0.4 Prodction
connected to an idle instance
```

So how to know how the process has been started to stop it properly?

Comment: Sounds like ORACLE_HOME might not be set correctly.

Comment: I set the ORACLE_HOME properly but maybe the guy who start the db not. So the trick is maybe how to find the ORACLE_HOME set by the active process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below command shows you the `ORACLE_HOME` used for that process.

`strings /proc/54621/environ | grep ORACLE_HOME`

Sometimes people add an unnecessary slash to the `ORACLE_HOME`, for example they use `/product/oracle/1120/db_1/` instead of `/product/oracle/1120/db_1`, which may cause the above issue.

Comment: Nice and easy solution! I just did a ls -l /proc/54621   to see the Oracle_home who started the process!